# npm start showing error after create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, web, npm, cmd, npm-start

i have been trying to create a new react app but not able to npm start it.
I am not able to understand the error msg. hope someone know it.
also i tried github deploy yesterday(if it helps).
the error i get after npm start is:-

```
D:\myportfolio>npm start

> myportfolio@0.1.0 start D:\myportfolio
> react-scripts start

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.43.213/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from D:\myportfolio\public
i ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
Starting the development server...

events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn powershell ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:273:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:469:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn powershell',
  path: 'powershell',
  spawnargs: [
    '-NoProfile',
    '-NonInteractive',
    '–ExecutionPolicy',
    'Bypass',
    '-EncodedCommand',
    'UwB0AGEAcgB0ACAAIgBgACIAaAB0AHQAcAA6AC8ALwBsAG8AYwBhAGwAaABvAHMAdAA6ADMAMAAwADAAYAAiACIA'
  ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myportfolio@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myportfolio@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-19T06_53_55_730Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Delete your node_modules folder, run npm start and then give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem recently and this fix for Windows worked for me:

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Go to System and Security -> System -> Advanced System Settings
3. Check out tab called Advanced then go to Environment Variables
4. Click on Path, edit it by adding "C:\Windows\System32" at the end of the path, separated by semicolon. For example (AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Windows\System32).

Lastly restart your computer for good measure. This is the only fix that worked for me after countless attempts to reinstall node modules.